# Sharepoint 2010 - Infopath form 2010 deployment

Tags: infopath, forms-services

An InfoPath form template can be published into SharePoint as

1. Form Library
2. Site Content type
3. Administrator approved form template

I have found lot of examples on how to deploy "Administrator approved form template" using powershell / WSP.

Any recommendations on how to publish to "Form Library" without Infopath designer 2010 (using powershell or wsp) will be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Deploying using Powershell scripts should be the better approach. You need to follow the below steps:

1. To upload the administrator-approved form template, type the following command:

   `Install-SPInfoPathFormTemplate -Path "FullPathName"`
2. To activate an administrator-approved form template to a site collection from the Central Administration site use the following command:

   `Enable-SPInfoPathFormTemplate -Identity "FormTemplateName" -Site "SiteCollectionURL"`

Follow [this Technet Article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262921.aspx) to get the full info of deploying Administrator approved form templates.

Comment: thanks.. but is it any powershell command/wsp approach to deploy non-admin approved template? As sandboxed solution or just to form-library without any code?